# Postgres: Find previous and next row or existing value created by SERIAL colum for separate query

Tags: postgresql, sequence, row

I got a Postgres 13 DB and a table with an id based on a SERIAL. After deleting rows such a sequence would have gaps.

In each row binary data is stored too and I would like to process it row after row moving backward or forward.

My idea would be to do `SELECT id FROM tbl;` and then use this as a lookup table. Another idea would be to create a view with a new continuous sequence and to get the max value and then iterate between sequence start and max value.

Example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl;
CREATE TABLE tbl (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
  name VARCHAR, 
  data BYTEA
);

INSERT INTO tbl (name, data) VALUES
  ('a', '0xff')
, ('b', '0xff')
, ('v', '0xff')
, ('w', '0xff')
, ('t', '0xff')
, ('u', '0xff')
;

DELETE FROM tbl WHERE id IN (3, 5);
```

As you can see the row id is having gaps.
I would like to do e.g. something like this (pseudocode):

```
std::vector<int> vec = SELECT id FROM tbl; -- -> Store values in C++ vector named vec

for(int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++) { -- Loop through vector resp. every row in the database table
    SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id=vec[i] -- Query every row in tbl
    //Do something with the binary data -- Process its data
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

If it plays a role, I am using `libpq`.

Comment: can you please provide a [mre]

Comment: Sorry, sure! Give me a sec.

Comment: Gaps in generated values are not a problem. The ***only*** job of a generated primary key is to be unique. It is completely irrelevant whether that value is 1,42,-534 or 5438947. There is nothing you need to do. Just move on.

Comment: Right, I can just get the row count and move on based on the row id and if the result is zero I move forward. Thanks

Comment: No need to get a row count "and move forward". Just insert a new row and let the sequence generate a new value.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the loop in pseudo-code, it seems like you want a SQL cursor.
it's instantiated with [DECLARE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-declare.html) associated to a query with an ORDER BY if needed, and you can use [MOVE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-move.html) to move forward or backward, and [FETCH](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-fetch.html) to fetch the current row, or several rows, and finally [CLOSE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-close.html) when you're done.

All these are SQL statements and independent from any client-side language.